# TFS 2017 Visual Studio Build task not generating output folders/files

Tags: visual-studio-2017, continuous-integration

I'm trying to build and deploy a core 2.1 website via a TFS build definition but whatever I do I just can't seem to get it to actually generate the build output.

Using VS2017, TFS2017 I have a build definition with includes an Visual Studio Build task with does the usual get sources, restore nuget, etc. then runs the build solution step.  It generates no errors...

```
Build started 16/07/2018 2:20:56 PM.
Project "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO.sln" on node 1 (restore target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "dev|any cpu".
Project "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO.sln" (1) is building "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj" (2:4) on node 1 (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target(s)).
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning : The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj]
Done Building Project "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target(s)).
Restore:
  Committing restore...
  Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO\obj\project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 87.44 ms for e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      C:\Users\tfs-buildsvc\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
      C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      \\WSBI010BLD\Nuget Packages
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
Done Building Project "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO.sln" (restore target(s)).

Build succeeded.

"e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO.sln" (restore target) (1) ->
"e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\dev\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj"

    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.00
[section]Finishing: Build solution **\*.sln
```

However, when I look in the build location of the build server, there is no bin folder generated.

I have tried both a Visual Studio Build task and an MSBuild task, the results are the same.  If I remote onto the server, open the solution and run a build with the source the build got from TFS, it works fine and creates the bin folder containing all the expected files.

I've also tried a variety of command line switches in the MSBuild Arguments options, according to the MS doco. and none makes any difference, from the simple...

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

...to the complex...

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile="Dev" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:publishUrl=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\publish
```

I've done loads of these for non-core projects with no problems, just the core ones are a problem.

Can anyone suggest why the output folders/files aren't appearing or suggest some other arguments to make the bin (etc.) files appear please.

**Edit:**

@Andy Li

I've overridden the gated check-in and forced a syntax error into the code - I've confirmed the error is in TFS - and the build still succeeds!  This suggests that, despite appearances, the build step is not actually attempting to compile the code.

I have checked the broken code has been checked out onto the build box (it is) and the code doesn't actually compile (it doesn't).  The build step is setup in much the same way as almost a hundred other 4.6.x builds we have which all work.  I just can't understand why it doesn't want to build this project.  Build stage of debug log...

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Build solution **\*.sln
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio Build
Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
Version      : 1.119.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613727)
==============================================================================
VstsTaskSdk 0.7.1 commit f990f8d8df6197b1cfcec01031ba014ad4905681
Entering E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\VSBuild.ps1.
Loading resource strings from: E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\Task.json
Loaded 8 strings.
SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
Loading resource strings from: E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
Loaded 8 strings.
INPUT_VSVERSION: 'latest'
INPUT_MSBUILDARCHITECTURE: 'x86'
INPUT_MSBUILDARGS: '/t:restore /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Dev.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True'
INPUT_SOLUTION: 'e:\ci\builds\30\s\**\*.sln'
INPUT_PLATFORM: 'any cpu'
INPUT_CONFIGURATION: 'dev'
INPUT_CLEAN: 'false'
Converted to bool: False
INPUT_MAXIMUMCPUCOUNT: 'false'
Converted to bool: False
INPUT_RESTORENUGETPACKAGES: 'true'
Converted to bool: True
INPUT_LOGPROJECTEVENTS: 'true'
Converted to bool: True
INPUT_CREATELOGFILE: 'false'
Converted to bool: False
INPUT_VSLOCATION (empty)
INPUT_MSBUILDLOCATION (empty)
INPUT_MSBUILDVERSION (empty)
Loading module from path 'E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\MSBuildHelpers.psm1'.
Loading resource strings from: E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\module.json
Loaded 9 strings.
SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
Loading resource strings from: E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
Loaded 9 strings.
Exporting function 'Format-MSBuildArguments'.
Exporting function 'Invoke-BuildTools'.
Exporting function 'Get-MSBuildPath'.
Exporting function 'Get-SolutionFiles'.
Exporting function 'Get-VisualStudio_15_0'.
Exporting function 'Select-MSBuildPath'.
Importing function 'Format-MSBuildArguments'.
Importing function 'Get-MSBuildPath'.
Importing function 'Get-SolutionFiles'.
Importing function 'Get-VisualStudio_15_0'.
Importing function 'Invoke-BuildTools'.
Importing function 'Select-MSBuildPath'.
Entering Get-SolutionFiles.
Solution: 'e:\ci\builds\30\s\**\*.sln'
Entering Find-VstsFiles.
LegacyPattern: 'e:\ci\builds\30\s\**\*.sln'
Entering Get-MatchingItems.
IncludePatterns: 'e:\ci\builds\30\s\**\*.sln'
ExcludePatterns: ''
IncludeFiles: 'True'
IncludeDirectories: 'False'
Force: 'False'
Path: e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln
Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
Total found: 1
Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
Leaving Get-SolutionFiles.
Entering Select-VSVersion.
PreferredVersion: 'latest'
Entering Get-VSPath.
Version: '15.0'
Entering Get-VisualStudio_15_0.
Getting latest Visual Studio 15 setup instance.
Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
FileName: 'E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe'
Arguments: '-version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json'
RequireExitCodeZero: 'True'
"E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json
[
{
"instanceId": "aad35b46",
"installDate": "2018-01-29T02:19:18Z",
"installationName": "VisualStudio/15.8.0+28010.0",
"installationPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise",
"installationVersion": "15.8.28010.0",
"displayName": "Visual Studio Enterprise 2017",
"description": "Microsoft DevOps solution for productivity and coordination across teams of any size",
"updateDate": "2018-08-17T08:27:56.1294346Z",
"enginePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\resources\\app\\ServiceHub\\Services\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service",
"layoutPath": "E:\\vs2017_limited",
"channelId": "VisualStudio.15.Release",
"channelPath": "C:\\Users\\he122322\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\Packages\\_Channels\\4CB340F5\\install_catalog.json",
"channelUri": "https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel",
"installChannelUri": "E:\\vs2017_limited\\ChannelManifest.json",
"releaseNotes": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=660692#15.8.0",
"thirdPartyNotices": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=660708"
}
]
Exit code: 0
Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
Leaving Get-VisualStudio_15_0.
Leaving Get-VSPath.
Leaving Select-VSVersion.
Entering Select-MSBuildPath.
PreferredVersion: '15.0'
Architecture: 'x86'
Defaulted MSBuild location method to: version
Entering Get-MSBuildPath.
Version: '15.0'
Architecture: 'x86'
Entering Get-VisualStudio_15_0.
Leaving Get-VisualStudio_15_0.
Loading C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll
MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe
Leaving Get-MSBuildPath.
Leaving Select-MSBuildPath.
Entering Format-MSBuildArguments.
MSBuildArguments: '/t:restore /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Dev.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True'
Platform: 'any cpu'
Configuration: 'dev'
VSVersion: '15.0'
MaximumCpuCount: 'False'
AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'TFS_620f346c-98e2-4693-ab12-3a966e56835f_build_11_805'
Leaving Format-MSBuildArguments.
Entering Invoke-BuildTools.
NuGetRestore: 'True'
SolutionFiles: 'e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln'
MSBuildLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'
MSBuildArguments: '/t:restore /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Dev.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="dev" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_620f346c-98e2-4693-ab12-3a966e56835f_build_11_805"'
Clean: 'False'
NoTimelineLogger: 'False'
CreateLogFile: 'False'
Entering Invoke-NuGetRestore.
File: 'e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln'
The 'Restore NuGet Packages' option is deprecated. To restore NuGet packages in your build, add a NuGet Installer task to your build definition.
Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]The 'Restore NuGet Packages' option is deprecated. To restore NuGet packages in your build, add a NuGet Installer task to your build definition.
AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY: 'C:\build agent'
Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\build agent\externals\nuget\NuGet.exe'
Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
FileName: 'C:\build agent\externals\nuget\NuGet.exe'
Arguments: 'restore "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln" -NonInteractive'
WorkingDirectory: 'e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop'
RequireExitCodeZero: 'True'
"C:\build agent\externals\nuget\NuGet.exe" restore "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln" -NonInteractive
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.8.166.59604' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
Restoring packages for e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj...
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 1.75 sec for e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj.
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\tfs-buildsvc\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
Feeds used:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
    \\WSBI010BLD\Nuget Packages
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Exit code: 0
Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
Leaving Invoke-NuGetRestore.
Entering Invoke-MSBuild.
ProjectFile: 'e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln'
MSBuildPath: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'
AdditionalArguments: '/t:restore /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Dev.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="dev" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_620f346c-98e2-4693-ab12-3a966e56835f_build_11_805"'
NoTimelineLogger: 'False'
Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=2688ddc5-4d3a-4a60-ad41-562c7fc3b523;type=Process;progress=0;state=Initialized;name=Build DDI.SSO.sln;starttime=2018-08-31T01:00:25.3347684Z]
Asserting leaf path exists: 'E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll'
Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
FileName: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'
Arguments: '"e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=2688ddc5-4d3a-4a60-ad41-562c7fc3b523|SolutionDir=e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop"*ForwardingLogger,"E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /t:restore /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Dev.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="dev" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_620f346c-98e2-4693-ab12-3a966e56835f_build_11_805"'
RequireExitCodeZero: 'True'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=2688ddc5-4d3a-4a60-ad41-562c7fc3b523|SolutionDir=e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop"*ForwardingLogger,"E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /t:restore /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Dev.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="dev" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_620f346c-98e2-4693-ab12-3a966e56835f_build_11_805"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 31/08/2018 9:00:25 AM.
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;parentid=2688ddc5-4d3a-4a60-ad41-562c7fc3b523;name=DDI.SSO.sln (Restore);type=Build;starttime=2018-08-31T01:00:26.2881392Z;state=InProgress;targetname=Restore;]
Project "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln" on node 1 (Restore target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "dev|any cpu".
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=73c68ed7-427e-4cbd-94f0-c4811f9f6729;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;name=DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj (_IsProjectRestoreSupported);type=Build;starttime=2018-08-31T01:00:26.9601879Z;state=InProgress;targetname=_IsProjectRestoreSupported;]
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=73c68ed7-427e-4cbd-94f0-c4811f9f6729;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;type=Build;result=Succeeded;finishtime=2018-08-31T01:00:26.9601879Z;progress=100;state=Completed;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;name=;]
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=7873c418-9d82-4a00-9634-8fcca2852c3e;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;name=DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj (_GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk);type=Build;starttime=2018-08-31T01:00:26.9914452Z;state=InProgress;targetname=_GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk;]
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=7873c418-9d82-4a00-9634-8fcca2852c3e;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;type=Build;result=Succeeded;finishtime=2018-08-31T01:00:27.0070763Z;progress=100;state=Completed;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;name=;]
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=2bb36beb-1520-4d9a-9b13-7df10128914c;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;name=DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry);type=Build;starttime=2018-08-31T01:00:27.0070763Z;state=InProgress;targetname=_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry;]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): Warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box).
Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Warning;sourcepath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets;linenumber=33;columnnumber=5;code=NETSDK1059;]The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box).
Project "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln" (1) is building "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj" (2:4) on node 1 (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target(s)).
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj]
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=2bb36beb-1520-4d9a-9b13-7df10128914c;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;type=Build;result=Succeeded;finishtime=2018-08-31T01:00:27.1008491Z;progress=100;state=Completed;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;name=;]
Done Building Project "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target(s)).
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=bca4ad22-be90-4117-b595-7eb1303a901f;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;name=DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj (_GenerateProjectRestoreGraph);type=Build;starttime=2018-08-31T01:00:27.1008491Z;state=InProgress;targetname=_GenerateProjectRestoreGraph;]
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=bca4ad22-be90-4117-b595-7eb1303a901f;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;type=Build;result=Succeeded;finishtime=2018-08-31T01:00:27.1164783Z;progress=100;state=Completed;parentid=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;name=;]
Restore:
  Restoring packages for e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj...
  Committing restore...
  Generating MSBuild file e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\obj\DDI.SSO.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\obj\project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 1.86 sec for e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      C:\Users\tfs-buildsvc\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
      C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      \\WSBI010BLD\Nuget Packages
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=d49754cc-1db8-4d38-a161-20dd8abaf3f9;parentid=2688ddc5-4d3a-4a60-ad41-562c7fc3b523;type=Build;result=Succeeded;finishtime=2018-08-31T01:00:29.5233487Z;progress=100;state=Completed;parentid=2688ddc5-4d3a-4a60-ad41-562c7fc3b523;name=;]
Done Building Project "e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln" (Restore target(s)).
Build succeeded.
"e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO.sln" (Restore target) (1) ->
"e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target) (2:4) ->
(_CheckForObsoleteDotNetCliToolReferences target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [e:\ci\builds\30\s\DDI.SSO\develop\DDI.SSO\DDI.SSO.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:03.81
Exit code: 0
Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail finishtime=2018-08-31T01:00:29.5858646Z;id=2688ddc5-4d3a-4a60-ad41-562c7fc3b523;progress=100;state=Completed;result=Succeeded]
Leaving Invoke-MSBuild.
Leaving Invoke-BuildTools.
Leaving E:\ci\builds\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\VSBuild.ps1.
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Build solution **\*.sln
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Do you mean .net core web application? Can you generate the output folders/files by running the msbuild command with the arguments locally? I mean run command on your develop machine or the build agent machine. Please enable the `system.debug` (set the value to `True` when queue a build), then queue the build again and share the entire log here for further troubleshooting.

Comment: @Andy Li - finally(!) back on this. Yes, this is a web application - more info included.  Can't include entire log as it is too big but I believe this part should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as it happens, turns out to be quite simple - don't use the *Visual Studio Build* or *MSBuild* tasks but rather use the *.NET Core* task, which is built for the purpose.

Despite its name, the *Visual Studio Build* task does not appear to be able to build dotNet Core projects (nor does the *MSBuild* task) but silently fails, giving the impression of no error when in fact it has not attempted to build the project at all.

You live and learn... 8-)